# New to jQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am wanting to make this function universal, based on button id. It currently works (somewhat) on one div, but there are multiple forms, in multiple divs on the page. Please advise...

```
var frm_submit_event = function(e) {
  var $this = $(this); // the button
  var frm = $('#' + selected_form_div + " form");
  console.log(frm);
  console.log(frm.serialize());

  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/forms/ajaxPost.php",
    data: frm.serialize(),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function($result) {
      //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this

      $('#' + selected_form_div).html($result);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('error handing here');
    }
  });
}

$(document).on("click", '.frm_submit_btn', frm_submit_event);
```

not sure where to go from here...

Comment: `var frm = $this.closest("form");` will get the form that the button is in.

Comment: What is `selected_form_div`?

Comment: `$('#' + selected_form_div).html($result);` will overwrite the form, since it's inside the DIV. Is that what you really want?

Comment: This is all the <script> on the file...
http://pastebin.com/01SJsspU

Comment: Text links display different forms (via jQuery) in subsequent divs. 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('._form_selector').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.get('classes/forms/forms.php', {
     form: $(this).attr('form_data')
    },
    function($result){
     $('#'+$this.attr('form_div')).html($result);
     selected_form_div = $this.attr('form_div');
     //console.log($result);
    });
    console.log($(this).attr('form_data'));
   });

Comment: Don't create custom attributes like `form_data`, use HTML5 data attributes like `data-form-data`.

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question, not comments or pastebin.com links.

Comment: In jQuery you can access them with `.data("form-data")`.

Comment: It's very unclear what your HTML looks like. Why do you need a global variable `selected_form_div`? Do you have multiple forms but only one submit button? Why don't you just put a submit button in each form, and use `$(this).closest("form")` to get the form of the button they click on. Or instead of binding to the buttons, use `$(document).on("submit", "form", ...)` to delegate a submit handler to all forms.

Comment: You seem to be making things much more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: I would love to simplify this, and it has gotten convaluted as I have mucked through it trying to get it to work. I am sure there is a simpler way to do this. 

$(document).on("click", '.frm_submit_btn', frm_submit_event); 

like that? which is already in place. As I review the logic, I am not sure why the buttons across divs are not working... which is (I think) the last hurdle to making this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement, checking the button id. With each case get/build the data from the button's respected form, then pass the data into the ajax call for posting.

Comment: What's a select statement, do you mean `switch`?

Comment: Sry yes a "switch" statement with each case building the data depending on the id of the button clicked.

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark as correct, or if you found a better solution, please post it so we all can share and learn.